# Snippets reviewed/edited feature

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I was thinking that the "big huge snippets" problem could be resolved with a new possibility:

If a snippet was copied from the question to the answer, I think it would be fine enough if the displayed snippet code showed only the code that was changed, and not the other unchanged content.

Some markup similar to what is already available with the "review edits" (from editing a post) feature would be really cool.

I was thinking of using it like `js hide: edited`

This avoids "surprises," but minimizes displayed code